# Remove function from memory when click on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'll try explain what I want to do. I have a resize function which runs when I press a button. This function opens two columns out of window and leave it out when the window is resized. However, I would like to reset that handler when I click on another div later. Just remove or clear that function from memory to avoid the resize. I have read some posts but any of them solve my problem.

My function to resize is:

```
function resizeColumnsOut(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var widthLeft = $('.column-left').outerWidth()+100,
            widthRight = $('.column-right').outerWidth()+100,
            vph = $(window).height();
        $('.options').css({'height': vph + 'px', 'overflow': 'hidden'});
        $('.column-left').css(
            {'transform': 'translateX(-'+widthLeft+'px)', 
            'transition': 'all ease-out .6s'});
        $('.column-right').css(
            {'transform': 'translateX('+widthRight+'px)',
            'transition': 'all ease-out .6s'});
    }).resize();
 }

$('[data-menu="close"]').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    resizeColumnsOut();
});
```

My function to reset the previous function when I click on:

```
function goAbout(){
    $('.about').click(function(){
      /* Events like .off() or .unbind() don't solve my problem since the resizeColumnsOut() function is already running */
    }
```

Comment: Yes, `.off()` is the way to go. If you mean that the animation is still running,  after doing `.off()` you need to set `transform:none !important` and `transition` with `.css()`.

Comment: @Spokey Thanks a lot, problem solved. I needed to play with on() and off() :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) instead:

Turn on with:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() { [code snipped] });
```

Turn off with:

```
$(window).off('resize');
```

Also you need to abort, or complete, the animations you have started. When you say your `resizeColumnsOut` function *is still running*, you actually meant the CSS animations it started are still going :)

Comment: I wasn't on the wrong track then, more or less :) Thank you so much for your time.